# How Insert Image using Picturebox and DataSet

Tags: c#

I have tried insert an image in my database across the dataset, but after the insert, I do not see the image in Database. I am using the `Byte[]` datatype to store the image data.

```
ImagE.Image = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
ImagE.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
photo_aray1 = stream.ToArray();

Program.Servicee.Emp_insert_other(FullnameETbox.Text, BirthdayETBox.Text, 
   RefrencePETBox.Text, PassportETBox.Text, MobileETBox.Text, 
   EmailETBox.Text, SkypeETBox.Text, AddressETBox.Text, 
   job_id_local, photo_aray1, UsernameTBox.Text, PasswordTBox.Text, 
   NoticeETBox.Text, clinics_id_local, clinic_id_local);
```

Comment: Please provide more detail on your problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where's the code that saves the image to the database? This just stores it in the variable `photo_aray1`.

Comment: Program.Servicee.Emp_insert_other(FullnameETbox.Text, BirthdayETBox.Text, RefrencePETBox.Text, PassportETBox.Text, MobileETBox.Text, EmailETBox.Text, SkypeETBox.Text, AddressETBox.Text, job_id_local, photo_aray1, UsernameTBox.Text, PasswordTBox.Text, NoticeETBox.Text, clinics_id_local , clinic_id_local);

Comment: I usw Web service in my application